# Place icons on the Chromebook desktop

Tags: desktop, google-chrome-os, chromebook, desktop-environments

I am accustomed to windows/mac/ubuntu/debian/mint/centos/rhel desktop operating systems which all have a "[desktop](https://superuser.com/tags/desktop/info)" (please see the link for the word "desktop" if you are not sure what a desktop is or what the desktop is in this specific context) where you can do something. Usually you can at least place icons (shortcuts to programs or files) or sometimes folders.

How can I place such icons on a Chromebook's desktop?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of features for the ChromeOS UI and a user manual?

Comment: I am asking specifically about the Chromebook desktop... Or to rephrase it: the part that has the wallpaper... Above the shelf. I've tried right clicking the wallpaper but you can't put any shortcuts or files or folders there. So I thought maybe I just haven't tried the right thing or maybe the only thing you can customize is the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

i asked this a while ago and since then:

- i have got no responses
- i haven't found any solutions personally after researching/trying

given the above, i think the answer is no.

Comment: @Worthwelle "this cannot be done" is absolutely an answer

Comment: @bertieb You're right. My mistake.